# Export SQL Server Data into CSV file on desktop data contain commas

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to export data into a CSV file from the SQL server. The code from this link ([Export SQL Server Data into CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458526/export-sql-server-data-into-csv-file)) is working with some except. In some rows that contain commas, the table arrangement is not correct. The code i have try

```
using (var connection = ConnectionToSqlServer.GetConnection())
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from  dbo.Test", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    string fileName = "test.csv";
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    object[] output = new object[reader.FieldCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
         {

           if (reader.GetName(i).Contains(","))
           {
              output[i] = "\"" + reader.GetName(i) + "\"";
            }
            else
            output[i] = reader.GetName(i);
           }
    }

    sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", output));

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.GetValues(output);
        sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", output));
    }

    sw.Close();
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It could be because the data is containing the commas. Try to quote the values.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you consider below options:

1. Quote the values, to have proper CSV generation. If the CSV content has `,` inside it, then the generated CSV might be having an issue.

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.GetValues(output);
    sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", $"\"{output}\""));
}
```

2. You can think of using library like [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-class-objects)